# Multiple threads accessing a single object but without data contention in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it ok to have a single object be accessed by two threads that modify different data-fields within that object. (There is no contention between the two threads as they operate on different data-fields of the same object).

But, since both of these threads will be accessing the same object (though modifying different data-fields of the same object), is there a possibility of corruption of object's state?

Is it **always** recommended to ensure mutually exclusive access to an object by multiple threads? Or is it ok to allow multiple threads to access the same object without any synchronization if they operate on different data-fields?

For example:
`class Foo
    {
        private Dictionary<string,ObjectA> map1;
        private Dictionary<string,ObjectB> map2;
    }`

Is it ok to have one thread modify objects of type ObjectA stored in map1 while another thread modifies objects of type ObjectB stored in map2?

Comment: check `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` in namespace `System.Collections.Concurrent`. I hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can do it without synchronization as you wrote.

Simply said, you need synchronization in these scenarios whenever you modify the same object from two threads, or when you modify it and read the same object in parallel. Your map1 and map2 are two distinct objects, you don't need to sync them.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing thread safety in this fashion is a bad design choice. It can work but it is very brittle and prone to being misused.

This is a complex subject and hard to answer briefly, but you should use an established access pattern that uses any one of [locking](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+thread+safety+locking), [synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+thread+safe+synchronization), or a thread safe [collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that's already baked into the .Net framework.

Comment: Is it really a bad design? It can be hard to maintain this kind of source code because it is unclear on the first sight if it is thread safe or not, but these sync-free techniques are often used to make the code simply faster.